# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15ML'

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

When I used to run this code I have this error. I have tried to solve it by others method but they are not sophisticated.
The dataset looks like this:

[[image: table of data]]

And my code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

regressor = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 10, random_state = 0)
regressor.fit(df_train, y_train)
```

Error trace:

> File "C:\Users\Acer
>   15\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433,
>   in check_array array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order,
>   copy=copy) ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15ML'

Comment: What is the error? And could you somehow format your input data in the question section rather posting an image?

Comment: File "C:\Users\Acer 15\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
    array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15ML'

Comment: What're the other methods that you tried that are not sophisticated?

Comment: Error is due to `15ML` being a string with numeric as well as string characters not been able to be converted to `float`. You need to process the data-set to make it work. Is your data-set in DB? or pandas dataframe?

Comment: pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `15ML` to `15` in pandas dataframe,

```
df['Quantity'].replace('15ML','15')
```

I have assumed the column name for `15ML` column is `Quantity`. You should replace with the actual column name that you've. If you want to access by location, you can also use

```
df.ix[:,4].replace('15ML','15')
```

I have counted including the index column in the image. Actual location may vary according to how you load the data.